# Rspec test with HTTP post request passes locally but fails on CI server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, http-post, codeship

I have an Rspec test that makes a POST request and sends a header with it because authentication is required:

```
it 'creates a client for an organization if none exists' do
  VCR.use_cassette('create_client') do
    post "/organizations/#{@organization.id}/clients", nil, { 'TOKEN' => @token }

    expect(last_response.status).to be(201)
    expect(json_response).to be_a(Hash)
    expect(json_response["organization_id"]).to eq(@organization.id)
    expect(json_response.keys).to include('auth_token')
   end
   expect(@organization.client).to_not be_nil
end
```

This passes without problems when I run the tests on my local machine, but will fail on the CI server (in this case Codeship):

```
Failure/Error: post "/organizations/#{@organization.id}/clients", nil, { 'TOKEN' => @token }
MyModule::MyClass::Errors::InvalidOptionError:
  bad URI(is not URI?):
```

When I remove the header part from the post request, the test will obviously fail because the token header is required, but the post request will go through without errors.

Any ideas why this is happening? I'd appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a problem with Elasticsearch on Codeship.